# The compiled jar IDEA does not start

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I use IDEA. The Swing application. Created an artifact. Specified Main-Class - MANIFEST created in the root `src\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF`

Content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.Main
```

In the compiled jar, the manifest is on the path `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

Tried through CMD - all is launched. But I need double click on jar file for open it.

What is the problem?

Comment: I don't understand. What command did you use to launch it on CMD and what are you trying to do?

Comment: What does "But I need what would be on the jar-u opened." mean?

Comment: @sleeplessnerd  Sorry. I changed the message. CMD command `java -jar file.jar`